# 'ServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'GetService'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

Using .net 6.0.101 in a console application `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` gives me the error described calling the `GetService` method.

```
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection();
serviceProvider
    .AddLogging()
    .AddSingleton<IParentPublisher, ParentPublisher>()
    .AddDbContext<LPContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration["connectionstring"]))
    .BuildServiceProvider();

serviceProvider
            .GetService<ILoggerFactory>()
            .AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your `serviceProvider` should actually be named `serviceCollection`. Secondary - [`AddConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.consoleloggerextensions.addconsole?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) should be called on `ILoggingBuilder` parameter of `AddLogging` (this is quite [old](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/logging-nonaspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0) change) and does not have overload accepting log level for latest packages.

So your code should look something like this:

```cs
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection
    // add stuff     
    .AddLogging(builder => builder.AddConsole());
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
var loggerFactory = serviceProvider
    .GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
```

You can set up [console log level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line#log-level) via appsettings:

```json
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Microsoft": "Warning"
        },
        "Console": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Microsoft": "Debug"
            }
        }
    }
}
```